# Unit testing Grails controller chaining

Tags: unit-testing, grails, controller, chain

I am unable to figure out how to test for a controller action that does 'chain'. I would like to verify the action.

Grails: 2.4.2

Controller:

```
class MyController {

def index() {

}

def doesChain() {
    chain action: 'index', model: [name: "my name"]
}
```

}

Test:

```
@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {

def setup() {
}

def cleanup() {
}

void "Action doing chain"() {

    when:
    controller.doesChain()

    then:
    controller.chainModel.name == "my name"
    controller.actionName == "someAction" // fails as actionName == null
}
```

}

Testing the action name is not passing as the actionName appears to be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "Action doing chain"() {

        when: 'an action invokes the chain method'
        controller.doesChain()

        then: 'the model is as expected'

        // either of these should work, you don't need both...
        controller.chainModel.name == "my name"
        flash.chainModel.name == "my name"

        and: 'the redirect url is as expected'
        response.redirectUrl == '/my/index'

    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Actually already tried that but only got '/' as redirectUrl. How ever, inspired by your example I created new controller and test for it, and vóla it works! Reason it returned '/' for my other controller was that it was the default mapped in UrlMappings.groovy: "/"(controller:"my"). This config was picked up end the 'my/index' was just mapped to '/'. So problem solved. Thanks!